# Django queryset: All Model1 objects where a Model2 exists with a model1 AND the given user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models and a `User`, related like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...


class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
```

Given a `User`, how do I get this queryset:

All `Model1` objects where a `Model2` exists with the model1 object AND the given `User`.

If I could imagine the table:

```
Model2 User Model1
1      1    1
2      1    2
3      1    2
4      1    4
5      2    1
6      2    3
```

I'm trying to get the queryset of Model1's for a user, say user=1, which would result in the Model1 objects [1,2,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through Model2:

    <s>Model2.objects.filter(model1=model1, user=user) \
        .values_list('model1', flat=True) \
        .distinct()</s>

First you filter out all Model2's with user as their user and then create a list of distinct Model1's.

```
list(set([m2.model1 for m2 in Model2.objects.filter(user=user).all()]))
```

In your specific example:

```
list(set([m2.model1 for m2 in Model2.objects.filter(user_id=1).all()]))
```

**UPDATE**

Try this too:

```
Model1.objects.filter(model2__user=user)
```

Comment: Either I don't understand (likely) or my question wasn't clear (also likely), specifically, what is model1=model1?  I'm not looking to filter based on a specific `Model1` object, I want all of them that are linked to the user via `Model2`

Comment: I added clarification to the question

Comment: The `list(set([...` works perfect and doesn't include duplicates of Model1.  The much more elegant Model1.objects.filter(...) also works, but includes duplicates of Model1 for the user if they exist.  Thank you!

Comment: @nima I'm trying the objects.filter solution for models UserProfile and Like, like so: `results = UserProfile.objects.filter(display_name__icontains=query, like__liker=request.user.active_profile)`, but it says `Cannot resolve keyword 'like' into field`. What can I do to fix that? thanks

Comment: @dietbacon This means that UserProfile is not connected to Like through a "like" property. something like this in the Like model: `liker = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='like')`

Comment: @nima thanks :) i never quite understood before now what related_name was for haha i had it as 'liker' and 'liked'.